# Terraform error refreshing state access denied

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform, bitbucket-pipelines, gitbucket

I'm using gitbucket for both my repository and for pipelines.
I have a terraform config file with a remote state configured which runs fine on my local machine however it fails when running in gitbucket. I keep getting access denied error.
Here's the main.tf:

```
terraform {
backend "s3" {
    bucket = "zego-terraform-test"
    key    = "test/terraform.tfstate"
    region = "eu-west-1"
  }
}

data "terraform_remote_state" "remote_state" {
  backend = "s3"

  config {
    bucket = "zego-terraform-test"
    key    = "test/terraform.tfstate"
    region = "eu-west-1"
  }
}

variable "region" {}

provider "aws" {
  region     = "${var.region}"
  access_key = {}
  secret_key = {}
  token      = {}
}

module "vpc" {
  source = "./modules/vpc"
}
```

Here's my gitbucket-pipelines.yml:

```
image: python:3.5.1
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
          - pip
        script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
          - apt-get update
          - apt-get install unzip
          - wget https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/0.11.7/terraform_0.11.7_linux_amd64.zip
          - unzip terraform_0.11.7_linux_amd64.zip
          - rm terraform_0.11.7_linux_amd64.zip
          - export PATH="$PATH:${BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR}"
          - terraform init
            -backend-config "access_key=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY"
            -backend-config "secret_key=$AWS_SECRET_KEY"
            -backend-config "token=$TOKEN"
```

When I run the .tf file in this pipeline I get this error:

```
Successfully configured the backend "s3"! Terraform will automatically
use this backend unless the backend configuration changes.
Error refreshing state: AccessDenied: Access Denied
    status code: 403
```

When I remove remote state config it runs fine.
Why am I getting the access denied error even though I'm using the same creds on my local machine and in gitbucket environment?

Comment: Are you sure your credentials are being read in properly? What happens if you have your pipeline run the `aws sts get-caller-identity` command from the AWS CLI?

Comment: For me setting the AWS_PROFILE correctly solved the issue.

Comment: For future readers, In my case, the region of the bucket was not correct.

Answer (score 23):

Was getting the same error. For our use case, we have to manually remove the `terraform.tfstate` file under `.terraform/` directory and run `init` again.

Comment: I'm using windows. I accidentally deleted contents inside terraform.tfstate file. After which when i attempt to delete terraform.tfstate file. Its automatically being recreated. i deleted the resource manually in cloud. Now i can't to get rid of this .tfstate file in windows local.

Answer (score 6):

In case a solution has not been found for this issue, you can use either "profile=" or "role_arn=" in the config section of your terraform_remote_state stanza.  The same is true for the AWS Provider and the backend configuration.

I chased this issue all day today not realizing that role_arn was available for terraform_backend_state data source.

Answer (score 4):

Same error happened to me when I was using several aws accounts using profile names.
In my case, I was missing `profile` property in the backend configuration. Added profile and removed `.terraform` directory, and ran `terraform init` - it worked.

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 1.0.0"
  backend "s3" {
    // here!
    profile = "crazyoptimist"
    bucket = "devops-terraform-crazyoptimist"
    key = "terraform.tfstate"
    region = "us-west-2"
    encrypt = true
  }
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 4.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  region = "us-west-2"
  profile = "crazyoptimist"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This error might occur when switching between terraform backends. To solve it you can run `terraform init -reconfigure` to configure the backend to the new one.

It will achieve the same result as removing the `terraform.tfstate` file under `.terraform` and run `terraform init`.

Answer (score 1):

At first glance it seems reasonable.  Have you tried having the terraform init and -backend-config's all on one line?  I wonder if the - at the beginning is messing with the yml format?

Answer (score 1):

received same error while running terraform init command in codebuild, simply gave s3 bucket access to role created for codebuild and error was resolved

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case the backend file of one of the data blocks of data.tf had permission issues, I just recreated that file and did terraform plan again, the problem sorted. Took ages to figure this out.

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "gateway" {
  backend = "s3"

  config = {
    bucket = "xxx-terraform-remote"
    key    = "xxx/terraform.tfstate"
    region = "eu-west-1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there was an issue with the order in which AWS client looks for credentials.

I stored AWS credentials used by terreform in  `~/.aws/credentials`, but I've also had different AWS credentials set in environment varaibles.

I had to remove AWS credentials from my env variables and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Terraform will need the following AWS IAM permissions on the target backend bucket:

s3:ListBucket on arn:aws:s3:::mybucket

s3:GetObject on arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/path/to/my/key

s3:PutObject on arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/path/to/my/key

s3:DeleteObject on arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/path/to/my/key

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aBSS.png)

Comment: It would be easier to understand the answer if you could expand on what you mean by path/to/my/key. Instead of inserting a screenshot of a documentation, please add a link to the documentation directly as it might contain other context that could help. Also if you use monospace for actions/ARNs the answer is easier to read, for example s3:ListBucket or arn:aws:s3:::mybucket. You can change a text to monospace by wrapping it in ` (backtick) characters.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the profile credential is valid however there is not enough permissions

Try:

1. Navigate `IAM -> Users -> wb-cli -> permissions tab -> Add permission`
2. Add `AdministratorAccess` or select the specific permissions you wish to grant the user.